# Permissions per git repository?

Tags: git

I have set up a git server in windows using the apache http mod.  Users come in through apache using their ldap credentials.  This works great except all users have access to pull/push all repositories.

How can I define which users have permission to push to the repository and leave it wide open for pulling?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an authorization layer like **[gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/)** in order to manage push/pull permissions.

You can plug it to your apache httpd server, following the documentation "[how to setup gitolite to use smart http mode](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/http.html)".